# How to create a tag panel in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a "tag" type of place (if I may say) to list every worker who's working in a specific project.

a better example.
[image: picture 1]

Where Users textbox is, I want to be a field with names/buttons of every worker that I have for a specific project.
To add projects will form, to add workers on a specific project too.

I want to find a way to show all the workers in 1 line.

And what kind of relationship should be used, Many to Many?

Comment: Create table for Users of project with structure `id`, `project_id`, `user_id`, `status`, `createdAt`, `removedAt`.

Comment: I have table for users and projects. even one to conenct them both. 
ID, project_id, user_id. but dont know how to show many in 1 place. cant understand the code for it

Comment: use [select2](https://select2.github.io/) or other plugins, when you will {search->Select->add user} to text box add `hidden <input>`s with id of users value. If you have the problem with SQL query please write below I will try to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an multiple selection select (using select2 library).

View:

```
<div class="form-group ">
<label for="users">Users</label>
<select id="users" name="users[]" class="select2" multiple required>
     @foreach($users as $user)
          <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
 </select>
 </div>
```

Example output:
[image]

It will generate an array with all selected users.

And yes, it would be a many to many relationship so you need an intermediate table to make them match

Comment: hey. thanks for this, made it. but the problem is that it doesnt show like buttons, and I  am not figuring it out.
it shows as a list text box

Comment: To reach the same result as my image, you have to import the Select2 library and initialize it on document ready. Check select2 docs where you can find full code examples. https://select2.github.io/ . Let me know if it is what you need

Comment: it is what I needed. I will try to import this and see if it works. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In users box you can write foreach to loop in to get all the user which has the same id of the project.
let's say you have project A and has id of 1 so alls users with project_id 1 show them

Relation one project hasMany users and users belongToMany projects

Comment: if you want to use select2 it's not a probleem and here is the javaScript for it . <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#user').select2({
            placeholder : "Select user",
            tags : true
        });